# Regex return undefined in a JavaScript String

Tags: javascript, regex, string, undefined

I have a little code snippet where I use Regular Expressions to rip off punctuation, numbers etc from a string. I am getting undefined along with output of my ripped string. Can someone explain whats happening? Thanks

```js
var regex = /[^a-zA-z\s\.]|_/gi;

function ripPunct(str) {
  if ( str.match(regex) ) {
     
          str = str.replace(regex).replace(/\s+/g, "");
  }
  
  return str;
}

console.log(ripPunct("*@£#__-=-=_+_devide-00000110490and586@multiply.edu"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass a replacement pattern to the first `replace` method, and also use `A-Z`, not `A-z`, in the pattern. Also, there is no point to check for a match before replacing, just use `replace` directly. Also, it seems the second chained `replace` is redundant as the first one already removes whitespace (it contains `\s`). Besides, the `|_` alternative is also redundant since the `[^a-zA-Z\s.]` already matches an underscore as it is not part of the symbols specified by this character class.

```js
var regex = /[^a-zA-Z\s.]/gi;

function ripPunct(str) {
  return str.replace(regex, "");
}

console.log(ripPunct("*@£#__-=-=_+_devide-00000110490and586@multiply.edu"));
```

Comment: Thanks, really helped. Thumbs up